# Python tkinter Grid Manager doesn't place button on left with sticky = tk.W or sticky = 'w'

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, sticky

With two frames within a frame, button placed in top frame,  sticky=tk.W doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
import tkinter as tk
def _exit():
    raise SystemExit

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root,width = 1200, height = 650, bg = 'Yellow')
top_frame = tk.Frame(frame, width = 1200, height = 50, bg = 'green')
bot_frame = tk.Frame(frame, width = 600, height = 600, bg = 'skyblue') 
exit_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text = 'Exit',
                    command = _exit)
frame.grid()
top_frame.grid(column=0,row=0)
bot_frame.grid(column=0,row=1)
exit_button.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky = tk.W)
                      
root.mainloop()
```

If I delete the bottom frame,  the sticky works :

```
import tkinter as tk
def _exit():
    raise SystemExit

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root,width = 1200, height = 650, bg = 'Yellow')
top_frame = tk.Frame(frame, width = 1200, height = 50, bg = 'green')
exit_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text = 'Exit',
                command = _exit)
frame.grid()
top_frame.grid(column=0,row=0)
exit_button.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky = tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place a button inside of `top_frame`, it will shrink to fit the button. The button *is* to the left of `top_frame`, but `top_frame` is only as wide as the button and is centered in its space. Therefore it appears that the button isn't on the left, but it is. The button is on the left edge of `top_frame`, but `top_frame` is centered in `frame`.

If you want `top_frame` to fill the width of the window (or the width of the space allocated to it) you need to use `sticky` with it, too.

```
top_frame.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky="ew")
```

Comment: Thank You, Bryan.  That works.  Your explanation helped a lot.